# SBT maven local repository is not searched

Tags: scala, maven, sbt

I want to load some library from local maven repostory. I have configured .sbt/0.13/plugins/plugins.sbt:

```
resolvers += Resolver.sonatypeRepo("snapshots")
resolvers += Resolver.mavenLocal

addSbtPlugin("org.ensime" % "ensime-sbt" % "0.1.5-SNAPSHOT")
```

In my project I have set this lines in build.sbt:

```
name := "hello"
version := "1.0"
scalaVersion := "2.10.4"
libraryDependencies += "opencv" % "opencv" % "2.4.9"
libraryDependencies += "opencv" % "opencv-native" % "2.4.9"
```

And I can't figure out why it is not working. After running sbt compile in project it logs this:

```
[info] Resolving opencv#opencv;2.4.9 ...
[info] Resolving opencv#opencv;2.4.9 ...
[warn]  module not found: opencv#opencv;2.4.9

[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   C:\Users\Una\.ivy2\local\opencv\opencv\2.4.9\ivys\ivy.xml

[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/opencv/opencv/2.4.9/opencv-2.4.9.pom

[info] Resolving opencv#opencv-native;2.4.9 ...
[info] Resolving opencv#opencv-native;2.4.9 ...
[warn]  module not found: opencv#opencv-native;2.4.9

[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   C:\Users\Una\.ivy2\local\opencv\opencv-native\2.4.9\ivys\ivy.xml

[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/opencv/opencv-native/2.4.9/opencv-native
-2.4.9.pom

[info] Resolving org.scala-lang#scala-compiler;2.10.4 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-lang#scala-reflect;2.10.4 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-lang#jline;2.10.4 ...
[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: opencv#opencv;2.4.9: not found
[warn]  :: opencv#opencv-native;2.4.9: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
```

Why it could be not looking in .m2/repository as said in plugins.sbt?

I have no experience with scala and sbt.

Comment: Is your local maven repo in standard place ? Also, can you set in build.sbt logLevel := Level.Debug and provide those logs?

Comment: One more question: SBT version?

Comment: SBT version is 0.13.7.

Comment: It is a standard place I think. opencv-2.4.9.jar for example is here C:\Users\Una\.m2\repository\opencv\opencv\2.4.9.

Comment: Here is the debug log https://gist.github.com/protsenkovi/a117c85214f8cf841e62

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move maven local resolver out of plugins.sbt and into build.sbt. If you want that listed plugin to come from the snapshot resolver listed leave that in plugins.sbt otherwise remove that one as well and move to build.sbt.