# SBT ignores file resolver to local maven repo

Tags: scala, maven, sbt

I'm trying to use dependency that is published to local maven repo. I'm using SBT 0.13.7 under Windows with JDK8. Here is what I tried in my `build.scala`

```
resolvers ++= {
  val mavenLocal = Resolver.file("local2", file(Path.userHome + "/.m2/repository"))(Resolver.mavenStylePatterns)

  Seq(
    mavenLocal,
// Resolver.publishMavenLocal,
    "spray releases" at "http://repo.spray.io/",
    "spray nightlies" at "http://nightlies.spray.io/",
    "jasperreports" at "http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/maven2/",
    "Akka Snapshot Repository" at "http://repo.akka.io/snapshots/",
    "Miredot" at "http://nexus.qmino.com/content/repositories/miredot"
  )
}
```

Strangely it doesn't work for me. I'm monitoring system file activity and SBT doesn't even try to go to above mentioned folder. I even tried to use provided `Resolver.publishMavenLocal`.

Here is what I get in the log

```
[warn]  module not found: com.wordnik#swagger-jersey2-jaxrs;1.5.2-M2-SNAPSHOT
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   C:\Users\root\.ivy2\local\com.wordnik\swagger-jersey2-jaxrs\1.5.2-M2-SNAPSHOT\ivys\ivy.xml
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/wordnik/swagger-jersey2-jaxrs/1.5.2-M2-SNAPSHOT/swagger-jersey2-jaxrs-1.5.2-M2-SNAPSHOT.pom
[warn] ==== local2: tried
[warn] ==== spray releases: tried
[warn]   http://repo.spray.io/com/wordnik/swagger-jersey2-jaxrs/1.5.2-M2-SNAPSHOT/swagger-jersey2-jaxrs-1.5.2-M2-SNAPSHOT.pom
[warn] ==== spray nightlies: tried
[warn]   http://nightlies.spray.io/com/wordnik/swagger-jersey2-jaxrs/1.5.2-M2-SNAPSHOT/swagger-jersey2-jaxrs-1.5.2-M2-SNAPSHOT.pom
[warn] ==== jasperreports: tried
[warn]   http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/maven2/com/wordnik/swagger-jersey2-jaxrs/1.5.2-M2-SNAPSHOT/swagger-jersey2-jaxrs-1.5.2-M2-SNAPSHOT.pom
[warn] ==== Akka Snapshot Repository: tried
[warn]   http://repo.akka.io/snapshots/com/wordnik/swagger-jersey2-jaxrs/1.5.2-M2-SNAPSHOT/swagger-jersey2-jaxrs-1.5.2-M2-SNAPSHOT.pom
[warn] ==== Miredot: tried
[warn]   http://nexus.qmino.com/content/repositories/miredot/com/wordnik/swagger-jersey2-jaxrs/1.5.2-M2-SNAPSHOT/swagger-jersey2-jaxrs-1.5.2-M2-SNAPSHOT.pom
```

Am I missing something ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SBT maven local repository is not searched](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27646685/sbt-maven-local-repository-is-not-searched)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I usually use this line when I need to import libraries from my local maven repository:

```
resolvers += "Local Maven" at Path.userHome.asFile.toURI.toURL + ".m2/repository"
```

Comment: Wow, that worked. I wonder what exactly wrong with version from SBT documentation.

Answer (score 0):

SBT 1.3.8 won't resolve maven local unless you try this:

- add a file with name repositories under `c:\Users\mac\\.sbt\`, and add:

  ```
  [repositories]

  maven-local
  ```
- start sbt with argument `-Dsbt.override.build.repos=true`.

Read the sbt online document carefully and you can find the answer.

Answer (score 0):

`resolvers += Resolver.mavenLocal`

Answer (score 0):

For sbt 1.5.5 (as mentioned by Victor Ma) I had to create a repositories file - `~/.sbt/repositories` and add `maven-local` to it. A couple of points - you don't need to provide any sbt arguments as sbt picks up the file automatically. You also need to provide the rest of the repositories that you need so other dependencies can be resolved too. As a bare minimum you'll need:

```
[repositories]

local
maven-local
maven-central
```